# TimeZone convertion in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

Im my application.rb I've set: config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'. It's ok when I save datetimes in the system. The problem is that I receive datetimes from another system that is already on the correct timezone. So, when this datetime is saved on my RoR system, it's being saved wrongly. Example: The another system sends a datetime 2015-11-10 15:07:00 (that is already on the right timezone, ready to save). But my RoR saves it like 2015-11-10 13:07:00 -0200. Is there a way to tell Rails that this datetime is already on the correct timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Rails/Ruby which timezone the incoming datetime is in, see a list of timezones using `rake time:zones:all` and then use the right one in the following code, eg.

```
Time.use_zone("Montevideo") { Time.zone.parse "2015-11-10 15:07:00" }
```

That will return an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object with the correct timezone set, and then you'll just store it in your DB and Rails will convert it to the correct UTC time.